# Vue Js 2 / Vue-CLI 3 / When hosted shows empty blank page

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

Vue Js app working fine in dev mode, but as I upload it on the server, it simply displays a blank page. All the resources are showing up in the developer console. I am using vue-router package.

VueJs 2 / Vue-CLI-3

Below is my App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <m-nav/>
    <router-view></router-view>  
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from './components/Navbar.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    'm-nav':Navbar

  }
}


</script>



<style>

</style>
```

This is my main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'
import HomePage from './components/HomePage.vue'
import Brochure from './components/Brochure.vue'
import Register from './components/Register.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
    {
        path:'/',
        component: HomePage
    },
    {
        path:'/download',
        component: Brochure
    },
    {
        path:'/register',
        component: Register
    }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: 'history'
});

new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

after running `npm run build`, It shows a blank page, although I can see some stuff in the DOM `<div id="app"></div>`

http://prntscr.com/lvasvo

I am not getting, where I have made a mistake! The project is complete, but stuck on this part! :(

Comment: got same problem, and also hash mode works well without query param

Answer (score 2):

follow this tips:

1. use <%= BASE_URL %> for script and link tags which wrote on index.html
2. create vue.config.js in root of project and config your public path for production and development mode like:

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "/" : "/"
  }
};
```

just use relative path, to know more about it, read this link:

https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath

create config.vue.js

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was in the `Router.beforeEach` function that I had in index.js file inside the router folder to add a route guard. I had to rewrite it after upgrading it from Vue 2 to Vue 3 to make it work.

Comment: This just saved me so much time ty, was working fine on local serving the app but moving to production w/apache app just continuously loaded with white screen.

Answer (score 0):

Just encounter the same issue with vue-cli3 project.
And my main reason getting this issue is my app doesn't deploy on the root of the domain,instead on a sub-path.

There're several tricky configures:

1. `vue.config.js` (it's [`vue-cli3`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) exclusive): to set `publicPath:/my-app/` ;
2. `router.js` (assuming your [`vue-router`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base) config file is this): to set `base:/my-app/`;
   And beware of the **history** router mode:

   - this mode needs extra [server side config](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations), I'm using nginX, this is my config:

   ```
   location /my-app {
            alias /var/www/my-app;
            try_files $uri /index.html last;
            index index.html;
   }
   ```

   And beware of the different between `alias` and `root`.

   - this mode is not support relative path `publicPath:./` in `vue.config.js`.